# Interrupt handling Free RTOS + ARM cortex A9

Tags: arm, interrupt, freertos

I have implemented Interrupt handling for Free RTOS running on ARM cortex A9 ( Zedboard). I am facing the following problem.

I am able to see that the interrupt line is being raised ( by checking spi_status register for the corresponding interrupt)

But the interrupt is not being caught by Free RTOS

I also see this condition, I can see that for my interrupt the set-enable ( ICDISER) bits are set, but when i raise the interrupt line for that corresponding interrupt, The set enable bits are getting reset. I raise my interrupt when a Free Rtos task is running. This is quite weird and I do not know why the Set-enable bits for that interrupt is being reset when I raise my interrupt line. Any ideas would be appreciated?

I know this question is quite specific to Free rtos, but i am actually un-aware why the set-enable bits for the interrupt is being reset ( quite weird in my opinion), so does not any one know why this happens?

Regards,
N

Comment: Are you checking the status registers via a debugger or via software running on the target?